# Select of multiselect not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiselect option of JQuery:

```
            <select multiple="multiple" id="add_remove_user_segment" size="5" name="add_remove_user_segment[]">
                <optgroup label="test">
                    <option value="test1">
                        test1
                    </option>
                    <option value="test2">
                        test2
                    </option>  
                    <option value="test3">
                        test3
                    </option>  
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="op1">
                    <option value="op1">
                        op1
                    </option>
                    <option value="op2">
                        op2
                    </option>  
                    <option value="op3">
                        op3
                    </option>  
                </optgroup>
            </select>
```

However whatever I select in javascript the following line of code gives me null! Why is that?

```
alert($("#add_remove_user_segment").val());
```

If my question is not clear please let me know!

Comment: there is no `id` of `my_select`

Comment: I Updated the one which does not work! Sorry

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/339JN/

Comment: I was about to answer your deleted question `onlick not working for my image` to give you a hint how to easily find typos. In the chrome devtools you can see on the console the error message. Check my profile for links.
Have you solved this question `Select of multiselect not working`  or do you need more help?

Answer (score 0):

`#my_Selelect` isn't the ID of your `<select>`, it's `#add_remove_user_segment`

Update:

It's returning `null` because it's running without anything being selected. Here is a fiddle to demonstrate that you need an `onchange` event to grab the value (or at the very minimum, try grabbing the value ONLY when something is selected)

http://jsfiddle.net/Dtxjv/1/

Answer (score 0):

## add_remove_user_segment has no value until you select one.

Your jQuery runs at document load before a value can be selected.

You need to test for on change or add a delay. demo here

http://codepen.io/lpoulter/pen/ukmwy